# How to Decrease HTML A4 size margin in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in CSS. I have a CSS code of A4 Size Page. I want to reduce top margin of my A4 size HTML page.

I tried too much time but I failed can anyone one please help me?

Please run the code snippet in full page view to see the correct result of  the code.

```css
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #F0F0F0;
 font: 12pt "Times New Roman";
    }
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .page {
        width: 210mm;
        min-height: 297mm;
        padding: 18mm;
        margin: 5mm auto;
        border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  
    }
    .subpage {
        padding: 1cm;
        border: 5px solid;
        height: 257mm;
        outline: 2cm #FFEAEA solid;
    }
    
    @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 0;
    }
    @media print {
        html, body {
            width: 210mm;
            height: 297mm;  
   -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact    
        }
        .page {
            margin: 0;
            border: initial;
            border-radius: initial;
            width: initial;
            min-height: initial;
            box-shadow: initial;
            background: initial;
            page-break-after: always;
        }
  hr { 
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1px;
border-top: 2px solid #009;

} 
   a:link {
    text-decoration: black;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: black;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<div style=" margin:auto; width:60px; height:auto; align: middle">
    Test Text
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: did you try removing the margin and padding of ".page"?

Comment: @Woncker Thank You Dear. Its working :)

Answer (score 0):

try by assigning margin at all side.

```
 @page {
            size: A4;
            margin: 0 1em 1em 1em;
        }
```

and remove margin and padding from other classes which may affect the page.